# Issues with off-canvas mobile menu in Bootstrap 3

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using offcanvas for a navigation in Bootstrap 3 that works perfectly fine in a desktop browser when the width of the window is made smaller, however on iOS devices the offcanvas part of navigation simply doesn't show once you click the menu button - it just indents -80% as you would expect - this is the case in both Safari and Chrome for iOS.

It does work in the browser and on Android devices however, just a no-go for Safari and Chrome (probably all browsers) on iOS. I have tried playing around with the CSS extensively - more changes than i can even attempt to list here - no doubt the issue is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't point a finger on what's missing right now, but I did just this the last few days on a site I'm working on. Because of my sticky header, I move the .navbar-collapse to body on small screens, by javascript.
My CSS looks like this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none;
    height: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding-top: @grid-padding*2;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    .transition;
    overflow: scroll;
}



 .navbar-collapse.in {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

And my js, like this

```
if (windowWidth > 767) {
    if ($("#MainNav-collapse").parent().is("body")) {
        $("#MainNav-collapse").appendTo("#MainNavBar");
    }
}
else {
    $("#MainNav-collapse").appendTo("body");
}
```

Comment: This has solved my issue. Although because my code is different the menu doesn't quite match up, i can  now at least see part of the navigation menu once the button is clicked. Perfect! Thank you.